# Update position in Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, raphael

Basicly, I have this scene, created with [Raphael](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3500/ztnn73rc_png.htm):

There is a jsfiddle of the problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5BgDe/21/).

So, my plan is to let the user cut of one of the ropes to create an Animation and open various new content while the ballon flies up and the scene changes....
I don't know if I should paste you my complete code, I'll just give it a try here:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  //initialisierung raphael
  var r = Raphael("Scene", "100%", "100%"),
    discattr = {
      fill: "#fff",
      stroke: "none"
    };

  //variablen zum verschieben und für positionierung
  var verschiebungX = 0;
  var verschiebungY = 0;

  //höhe auf welcher die ballons hängen
  var ballonHohe = 500;

  //die nägel
  nagel1 = new Array(225, 735);
  nagel2 = new Array(500, 735);
  nagel3 = new Array(775, 735);

  //wind offset
  var windOffset = 10;

  //die bilder einlesen und auf ihr plätze legen
  var bg = r.image("img/bg.jpg", 0, -800 + verschiebungY, "100%", "200%");
  bg.attr({
    "clip-rect": "0,0, 100% , 100%"
  });

  var brett = r.image("img/holz.png", 0, 700 + verschiebungY, "100%", "20%");
  brett.attr({
    "clip-rect": "0,0, 100% , 100%"
  });



  r.text(310, 20, "Welcome to LuckyCrew").attr({
    fill: "#fff",
    "font-size": 16
  });

  var foo = 0;

  //das BallonObject
  Raphael.fn.ball = function(x, y, r, hue) {
    hue = hue || 0;
    return this.set(
      this.ellipse(x, y, r, r * 1.15).attr({
        fill: "r(.5,.9)hsb(" + hue + ", 1, .75)-hsb(" + hue + ", .5, .25)",
        stroke: "none"
      }),
      this.ellipse(x, y, r - r / 5, (r - r / 20) * 1.15).attr({
        stroke: "none",
        fill: "r(.5,.1)#ccc-#ccc",
        opacity: 0
      })
    );
  };

  //das seilObject
  function curve(x, y, ax, ay, bx, by, zx, zy, color) {
    var path = [
        ["M", x, y],
        ["C", ax, ay, bx, by, zx, zy]
      ],
      path2 = [
        ["M", x, y],
        ["L", ax, ay],
        ["M", bx, by],
        ["L", zx, zy]
      ],
      curve = r.path(path).attr({
        stroke: color || Raphael.getColor(),
        "stroke-width": 4,
        "stroke-linecap": "round"
      });
  }

  //die seile
  var firstCurve = curve(
    (nagel1[0] + (windOffset * 2)) + verschiebungX, ballonHohe + verschiebungY, (nagel1[0] + (windOffset * 1.5)) + verschiebungX, ballonHohe + 100 + verschiebungY, (nagel1[0] + windOffset) + verschiebungX, 650 + verschiebungY,
    nagel1[0] + verschiebungX, nagel1[1] + verschiebungY,
    "hsb(0, 0, 0)");

  var secondCurve = curve(
    (nagel2[0] + (windOffset * 2)) + verschiebungX, ballonHohe + verschiebungY, (nagel2[0] + (windOffset * 1.5)) + verschiebungX, ballonHohe + 100 + verschiebungY, (nagel2[0] + windOffset) + verschiebungX, 650 + verschiebungY,
    nagel2[0] + verschiebungX, nagel2[1] + verschiebungY,
    "hsb(0, 0, 0)");

  var thirdCurve = curve(
    (nagel3[0] + (windOffset * 2)) + verschiebungX, ballonHohe + verschiebungY, (nagel3[0] + (windOffset * 1.5)) + verschiebungX, ballonHohe + 100 + verschiebungY, (nagel3[0] + windOffset) + verschiebungX, 650 + verschiebungY,
    nagel3[0] + verschiebungX, nagel3[1] + verschiebungY,
    "hsb(0, 0, 0)");

  //die bälle
  r.ball(nagel1[0] + (windOffset * 2) + verschiebungX, (ballonHohe - 115) + verschiebungY, 100, Math.random());

  r.ball(nagel2[0] + (windOffset * 2) + verschiebungX, (ballonHohe - 115) + verschiebungY, 100, Math.random());

  r.ball(nagel3[0] + (windOffset * 2) + verschiebungX, (ballonHohe - 115) + verschiebungY, 100, Math.random());


  //die nägel auf die fäden hämmern
  var nagel1 = r.image("img/nagel.png", nagel1[0] - 25, nagel1[1] - 10 + verschiebungY, 50, 50);
  nagel1.attr({
    "clip-rect": "0,0, 100% , 100%"
  });

  var nagel2 = r.image("img/nagel.png", nagel2[0] - 25, nagel2[1] - 10 + verschiebungY, 50, 50);
  nagel2.attr({
    "clip-rect": "0,0, 100% , 100%"
  });

  var nagel3 = r.image("img/nagel.png", nagel3[0] - 25, nagel3[1] - 10 + verschiebungY, 50, 50);
  nagel3.attr({
    "clip-rect": "0,0, 100% , 100%"
  });


  var test = r.ellipse(50, 50, 40, 20);

  r.ball(50, 40, 20, Math.random());

};
```

In XNA or Processing, you have a `Update()` and `draw()` function given, in Java you have a `repaint()` function, not so in Raphael. I read about an .animate() function in the api, but since I want to manipulate the ballons(and ropes) dynamically I don't believe this is the right way here(proof me I'm wrong).

My question is how to reload the scene or at least update it...

Edit:
I also tried creating variables with objects and calling their creation in a function, then change parameters and repeat but this did not seem to work, too. The object in this case where not created after all.

Comment: Maybe I could use something like                                    "windOffset -= 5;
function();" (to call back to the first line) But this still does not work

Comment: You don't need to 'reload' the scene, you could probably just update the attr of an object (probably changing x,y or transform/translate), and use this with a requestanimationframe or setinterval maybe. When you change an attribute, Raphael/svg should update automatically on the screen.

Comment: I could create a circle of 0 px radius and use him to set the position of the other objects. But here I run into this problem: test.attr(cx) does not return the correct value. I tried the following:  var firstCurve = curve(
                      (nagel1[0] + (test.attr(cx)* 2)) + [...]      I could try to translate it with a rekursive method but it just does not pass the value.

Comment: Could you put a small example highlighting the problem on a jsfiddle ?

Comment: A JSfiddle has been added at the top of the page. When I can manipulate the ballon by changing the value of the var, I can also manipulate the hole scene. I just don't have a clue how to do this, I have already googled and read in the doc. Requesting help or an explanation, Ty -Lucky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one idea. I think the solution will partly depend on how you want the movement to look. SVG & Raphael will update as soon as you change any attributes (or animation/transform), so typically you won't have to worry about screen updates as such. (You may need to use more complex code and timing if you need more complex movement/animation).

I've put both of the elements into another set, and applying an animate transform to them. There is an 'easing' function I've included to try and slow the animation down at the ends, so it looks a bit smoother.

The key changes to the code are...

```
var ball = r.ball(100 + (windOffset * 2), 
 (250 - 115), 100, Math.random()); //the height of rope top - radius

var set = r.set(ball, firstCurve);

set.animate({ 'transform':  "t" + windOffset +",-100" }, 2000, "<>", function() {
    set.animate({ "transform" : "t0,-200" }, 2000, "<>" )} );
```

Working jsfiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/5BgDe/29/

The animation uses a transform string, "t100,200" for example would move the element by 100,200 (or the coordinate system, I would have a quick read into transforms if you're not aware already, just so they make sense a bit).

I have combined 2 animations, just as an example to show how you can combine them if you wanted 2 directions applied after each other. Here's a link to the animation docs as well if it helps http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.animate

Comment: Thanks, mate. With your example I am able to move objects. Now I need to know 2 more things: At first, I got me the bounding box of var balloon and wanted to move the rope with this by only moving the balloon, this won't work. Here's the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5BgDe/31/  ... My second idea was to do something like var set = r.set(ball1,firstCurve.x*2,firstCurve.y*1.5); This won't work, too. To make it more clear I don't just want the rope to move somewhere on the screen but let it follow the balloon.... Thanks so far.

Comment: btw I would upvote your comment but it says I need lvl 15 or something

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean (as the example moves both the rope and balloon which sounds like what you want), do you mean you want the bottom of the rope to be static but the top part of the attached balloon to move with it or something else ? I'm also not quite sure why you need a bounding box for anything atm.

Comment: Sorry if i made it not clear, yes i want the bottom to be static. I don't need the bounding box, thats true, but it was the fastest way to get x coordinates of ballon at this point (I guess). What about animating the curve's points alone(not the whole thing).

Comment: ok, think I've misunderstood what you were trying to achieve. I'm guessing you may need to use some manual timing and repositioning functions unfortunately (and bounding box possibly as you mention), so animation like I have suggested possibly isn't the way to go. It may be simpler if the line was just straight as you could possibly just adjust one end of the line to be the centre of the balloon or something.

Comment: should i open a new question based on the jsfiddle you created? \n I'm new to this site and don't have much clue how to get best results here

Comment: I think if you can break it down into minimal code and example, it maybe worth it (probably not with my fiddle as I'm not sure thats the way to go). Maybe break down to its core elements, so move a simple filled sphere, and a connected curved path, and get them to link up the bottom of the path with the sphere as it moves ?

Comment: Okay I will try this. For now +1 Karma to you.

Comment: I would also add the svg tag, as there may be some other suggestions than Raphael that could apply.